# Configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Tags: c++, ubuntu, configure, libtool

This error makes me crazy. I tried many solutions without success.
Here is my problem,  when I launch `./configure` to compile libtool I get this error:

```
....

checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/home/thierry/libtool-master/libtool-master':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

I can't show you `config.log` because of its size, and it has some binary characters in it.

I have all the compiler c++, g++, gcc as shown above:

```
thierry@LFR038391:~/DeepSpeech$ dpkg -l | grep c++
ii  libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64               2.10.0-2                           amd64        type-safe Signal Framework for C++ - runtime
ii  libstdc++-6-dev:amd64                 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04               amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++-7-dev:amd64                 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                      8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
thierry@LFR038391:~/DeepSpeech$ pwd
/home/thierry/DeepSpeech
thierry@LFR038391:~/DeepSpeech$ dpkg -l | grep gcc
ii  gcc                                   4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3                 amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-6                                 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04               amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-6-base:amd64                      6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04               amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-7                                 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-7-base:amd64                      7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-8-base:amd64                      8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc-6-dev:amd64                    6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04               amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc-7-dev:amd64                    7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:amd64                         1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1           amd64        GCC support library
thierry@LFR038391:~/DeepSpeech$ dpkg -l | grep g++
ii  g++                                   4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3                 amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-6                                 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04               amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-7                                 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1             amd64        GNU C++ compiler
```

I have no more ideas for how to solve this now.

Comment: You have three different GCC versions, but the one to use is not clear. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/313288)

Comment: it seems that c++ and g++ functions correctly but gcc no :

Comment: Yeah, a big mess for `configure`. Try the advices in the link I posted. Even unistall all three versions and reinstall the one you choose.

Comment: Using `/lib/cpp` as the preprocessor almost always indicates an error in compiler autodetection (in my experience on desktop systems). Read `config.log` to see what has `configure` tried to run when detecting the preprocessor, what has failed and why. That log usually has all the information you need.

Comment: gcc points to no valid link : since when i  try < which gcc>  , i get : </usr/bin/gcc > then when i try  <ls -lart /usr/bin/gcc> i get < /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-7 > ans then when i  try < ls -lart /usr/bin/gcc-7> i get  <  /usr/bin/gcc-7 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7>  and after the link stop :  ls -lart /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7   give < /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7 >

Comment: Hi Igor  i try to read my config.log but after some page it becomes binary and no readable ...

Comment: configure seems  now ok  but make failed with this short error :

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue yesterday what i have done is i installed all these RPMs in my VM then it started working well.

Most of these rpms are interdependent.

installed Pkgs

```
cpp-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm
glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm
glibc-devel-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
mpfr-3.1.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
gcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm
glibc-common-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm
glibc-headers-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm
libmpc-1.0.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.i686.rpm
```